# x86-64 Assembly code not running

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I am new to assembly. I'm attempting to learn by referencing from a book named "Writing Security Tools and Exploits". Anyone familiar with this book would know that the assembly code is written for 32bit but I'm build this on a 64bit system.

Due to this I have rewritten the code to run on 64bit. After successfully compiling the code the desired output is not accomplished when I attempt to run the program. Instead I receive no output.

I am building this on an AMD64 Debian Linux system. Here is the code I am trying to receive output from:

```
global _start
_start:
xor             rax,rax

jmp short string
code:
pop             rsi
push byte       15
push            rsi
push byte       1
mov             al,4
push            rax
int             0x80

xor             rax,rax
push            rax
push            rax
mov             al,1
int             0x80

string:
call code
db  'Hello, world !',0x0a
```

I compile it using the following commands

$> nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
   $> ld -s -o hello hello.o

When I attempt to run there is no output.

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming from this code you are attempting to create code for a stack based buffer exploit. For 64-bit code you should really be using `syscall` rather than `int 0x80`, and the 64-bit calling convention passes most `syscall` parameters in registers, rather than the stack.

Comment: If you run your code under `strace`, you'll get a trace of the system calls it made, with error codes.

Answer (score 1):

There is mainly one big problem in your code, you seems to believe that the calling convention (passing arguments) for the system call through `int 0x80` is passed by pushing it onto the stack. But, in fact, you need to go through the registers `eax`, `ebx` and `ecx` (see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux#int_0x80) for more details).

So, the proper way to write the code would be:

```
global _start
_start:
xor             rax,rax

jmp short string
code:
pop           rsi
mov           rdx, 15   
mov             rcx, rsi
mov             rbx, 1
mov             al,4
int             0x80

xor             rax,rax
mov             rbx, rax
mov             al,1
int             0x80

string:
call code
db  'Hello, world !',0x0a
```

Then, just do:

```
$> nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
$> gcc -nostdlib -o hello hello.o
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback everyone. Perror you're quite right. Can you suggest any books related to x64 Assembly I can follow up learning from as a lot of my reading is coming from dated books. It would be a lot of help if these were security focused.